# Corrupted linked list with 3 exact node values - where will it go?

Tags: list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Suppose the linked list has a loop:

A->B->Q->I->C->Q->P->H->Q->R

This list has 3 equal Q nodes. When the 2nd Q is met, where will the pointer go - to the first Q or last(third Q)?

I guess it will go back to the first occurrence of Q, since it does not 'know' the last ,3rd Q actually exists.

So having other Q nodes does not matter, since we already have a loop that will run between the first 2 Q's.
Am i correct? are there cases when it will randomly switch to what Q to select and go through?

Comment: Your example is impossible - `Q` must be followed by the same node every time. A loop example would have the structure `A->B->Q->I->C->Q->I->C->Q->I->...`.

Comment: Not enough details, please submit the relevant code and tag your question with the programming language you're using. "pointers" can get a different meaning in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the `next` field?

Unless you have faulty memory, the value will always be the same.

Approach this from a hardware perspective (where does the memory reference point to), not pen&paper.